# Filter Object, adjust it and replace

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a `fieldNames` array initialized to state. It looks something like this once it gets populated from a API call:

```
[
  { name: "joe",  type: "string" },
  { name: "bob",  type: "string" },
  { name: "mike", type: "string" }
];
```

I only care about the `name` key in this instance, since I'm using it in a checkbox function to keep track of `selectedFields`.

Said `checkbox` function:

```
checkbox = ({ name, isChecked }) => {
  //handle check box of each fieldName
  const obj = this.state.fieldNames.find(field => field.name === name);
  if (isChecked === true) {
    //checked conditional
    this.setState({
      selectedFields: {
        ...this.state.selectedFields,
        [name]: { ...obj }
      }
    });
  } else {
    const newSelectedFields = this.state.selectedFields;
    delete newSelectedFields[name];
    this.setState({
      selectedFields: newSelectedFields
    });
  }
};
```

So how I'm setting state here is immediately taking the selected name and turning it into an object, which is not what I want. The end data type/structure is not valid to send via my API.

For instance it ends up looking like this:

```
"selectedFields": {
  "joe": {},
  "bob": {}
}
```

Whereas, I need it to look like below. There are additional values added to these objects but that is separate from achieving this (I think).

```
[
  { name: "joe" },
  { name: "bob" }
];
```

Comment: If you have the structure you want, does it matter if the extra properties get sent along with it as long as you have the `name` field?

Comment: The only thing that I need from the original object is `name` key and it's value. I render those other properties in a table, but they are NOT used to create the new object, which is used in a data request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refactor your function to this

```
checkbox = ({ name, isChecked }) => {
  if (isChecked)
    this.setState({selectedFields: [ ...this.state.selectedFields, { name }]});
  else   
    this.setState({ selectedFields: this.state.selectedFields.filter(f => f.name !== name)});
};
```

One of the key mistakes you made was using the spread operator inside an object literal `{ ... }` instead of inside an array `[ ... ]`. In the else condition you also failed to use the spread operator and set the state to the same object which might prevent React from re-rendering as it may not detect the change in state. With the change to the object, it is no longer possible to use delete, use filter instead. Also, if you only need the name field, there is no need to use find on `fieldNames` as the name is already passed to the function.

(I also had to compress your function because I'm used to reading code that is as short as possible)

Edit: Some people like to go even shorter

```
checkbox = ({ name, isChecked }) => this.setState({selectedFields: isChecked ? [ ...this.state.selectedFields, { name }] : this.state.selectedFields.filter(f => f.name !== name) });
```

Comment: Your delete method is trying to delete from an array using a string key

Comment: I realised that

Comment: Thank you for clearing this up. Especially removing `delete`. I was also mutating state there so filtering makes a lot more sense.

Comment: Great solution. Just for kicks and giggles if you wanted to make it even shorter, you could use the ternary operator for setting `selectedFields` then use the shorthand in `setState` :) But I understand that some people don't prefer the tougher readability of that.

Answer (score 1):

Going off your code:
You need to make sure you're saving in the format you want, as well as removing the correct element by it's property value (name)

```
checkbox = ({ name, isChecked }) => {
  //handle check box of each fieldName
  const obj = this.state.fieldNames.find(field => field.name === name);
  if (isChecked === true) {
    //checked conditional
    this.setState({
      selectedFields: [
        ...this.state.selectedFields,
        { name }
      ]
    });
  } else {
    const newSelectedFields = this.state.selectedFields;
    newSelectedFields.splice(newSelectedFields.findIndex(obj => obj.name === name), 1);
    this.setState({
      selectedFields: newSelectedFields
    });
  }
};
```